# Retrospectively inactivate records - soft delete

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, sql-update

I currently have an ods table that stores financial instrument information. The table is loaded every day and updates are done with an SCD type 2 mechanism. This has been loading fine for a while but we have now received information from the business that if an instrument is no longer delivered then it should be marked as inactive. Therefore I need to create a query that retrospectively inactivates instrument records that have no longer been delivered. Each delivery has a Close Of business field (CobDate). When an Instrument record is no longer delivered, the CobDate field of the first delivery where is no longer delivered should be used to Endate the most recent record of that instrument in the ODS and set the Active flag to 'N'.

I have added some dummy data to illustrate the situation

```
Declare @table  as table( 
Instrument_Id int, 
rate decimal(10,5) , 
uninteresting  varchar(10) ,
CobDate date,
StartDate  datetime,
EndDate datetime,
CurrentVersion varchar(10),
Active varchar (1))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES 
(123  , 1.20   , 'foo' , '2010-10-10' ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2010-10-11 00:00:00.000'  , '1','N'),
(123, 1.2, 'baz', '2010-10-11','2010-10-11 00:00:00.000','2010-10-12 00:00:00.000'  , '2','N'),
(123, 1, 'ttt', '2010-10-12','2010-10-12 00:00:00.000', '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000'  , '3','Y'),
(456, 2.1, ' bar', '2010-10-10','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2010-10-11 00:00:00.000'  , '1','N'),
(456, 2, ' bar', '2010-10-11','2010-10-11 00:00:00.000','2999-12-31 00:00:00.000'  , '2','Y'),
(789, 1.95, 'quux ', '2010-10-10', '2010-10-10 00:00:00.000','2999-12-31 00:00:00.000'  , '1','Y')



select * from @table
```

In this example, the first CobDate is 2010-10-10 and the last one is 2010-10-12. Based on this the output should be as follows:

```
InstrumentId    rate    uninteresting    CobDate           StartDate                 EndDate                    CurrentVersion  Active
 123          1.20000       foo         2010-10-10     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000   2010-10-11 00:00:00.000                1           N
 123          1.20000       baz         2010-10-11     2010-10-11 00:00:00.000   2010-10-12 00:00:00.000                2           N
 123          1.00000       ttt         2010-10-12     2010-10-12 00:00:00.000   2999-12-31 00:00:00.000                3           Y
 456          2.10000       bar         2010-10-10     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000   2010-10-11 00:00:00.000                1           N
 456          2.00000       bar         2010-10-11     2010-10-11 00:00:00.000   2010-10-12 00:00:00.000                2           N
 789          1.95000       quux        2010-10-10     2010-10-10 00:00:00.000   2010-10-11 00:00:00.000                1           N
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what kind of "mechanism" you're looking for, but i'm gonna assume you need help generating Start, End, CurrentVersion and Active columns.

Here's a potential solution to your problem:

```sql
SELECT  Instrument_Id, rate, uninteresting, CobDate
,   CASE WHEN prevCoB IS NULL THEN '19000101' ELSE CobDate END AS StartDate
,   CASE WHEN nextCoB IS NULL THEN '29991231' ELSE nextCoB END AS EndDate
,   CurrentVersion
,   CASE WHEN nextCob IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Active
FROM    (
    SELECT  LEAD(cobdate) OVER(PARTITION BY instrument_id ORDER BY cobdate) AS nextCoB
    ,   LAG(cobdate) OVER(PARTITION BY instrument_id ORDER BY cobdate) AS prevCoB
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Instrument_id ORDER BY cobDate) AS CurrentVersion
    ,   Instrument_Id, rate, uninteresting, CobDate
    FROM    @table
) x
```

LAG/LEAD functions are used to get previous / next CobDate, and the obtained information allows to create the needed data.
Similarily, ROW_NUMBER generates a counter for the CurrentVersion.

You can use this data to update your original table

Comment: Thank you. This isn't quite what I was looking for but it has put me in the right direction. With instrument 456 there was nothing sent for CobDate 2010-10-12 so its end date should be  2010-10-12. I need to add another window function in the subquery to get the most recent CobDate over the whole set and then use it in the case statement for the Enddate.  Much appreciated